# How to manipulate a string of INSERT data and separate the values of the columns in the right way?

Tags: java, mysql, string

I have a small problem and I will try to explain briefly.

I have an INSERT from a MySQL DUMP and must identify the columns of this reading the .sql file with Java.

Following cases:

Case 1:

```
INSERT INTO `table_1` VALUES (1, 'Test data', 'other data', '2016-02-02');
```

I can extract this STRING value: 1, 'Test data', 'other data', '1/10/2016'
And I thought to do the split by comma (,) but I came across the following situation:

Case 2 and 3:

```
INSERT INTO `table_1` VALUES (2, 'Another row, with a comma', 'other data', '2016-01-02');

INSERT INTO `table_1` VALUES (3, 'Another row, with a comma and \' - more data ',' other data ',' 2016-01-01 ');
```

In these two situations above, I do not know how I identify and separate correctly columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a solution using regular expressions (I am not familiar with regex so maybe it can be done using another regex more efficiently) which works for the 3 kind of strings you provide:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "1, 'Test data', 'other data', '2016-02-02'";
        String str2 = "2, 'Another row, with a comma', 'other data', '2016-01-02'";
        String str3 = "3, 'Another row, with a comma and \' - more data ',' other data ',' 2016-01-01 '";


        splitAndPrintString(str1);
        splitAndPrintString(str2);
        splitAndPrintString(str3);
    }

    public static void splitAndPrintString(String str) {
        System.out.println("String: " + str + " splits to: ");
        String splitStr[] = str.split("(,')|(, ')");
        for(String s: splitStr) {
            System.out.println(s.replaceAll("'$", ""));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
String: 1, 'Test data', 'other data', '2016-02-02' splits to: 
1
Test data
other data
2016-02-02

String: 2, 'Another row, with a comma', 'other data', '2016-01-02' splits to: 
2
Another row, with a comma
other data
2016-01-02

String: 3, 'Another row, with a comma and ' - more data ',' other data ',' 2016-01-01 ' splits to: 
3
Another row, with a comma and ' - more data 
 other data 
 2016-01-01
```

**EDIT**
To accommodate also the case: "2,'Some data (\', hello\',)',NULL,'2016-02-10'"
use the following method (the if statement deals strictly with the NULL case):

```
public static void splitAndPrintString2(String str) {
    System.out.println("String: " + str + " splits to: ");
    String splitStr[] = str.split("(,')|(, ')");
    for(String s: splitStr) {
        if(s.endsWith("NULL")) {
            String prefix = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(","));
            String suffix = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(",")+1);
            System.out.println(prefix.replaceAll("'$", ""));
            System.out.println(suffix.replaceAll("'$", ""));
        } else {
            System.out.println(s.replaceAll("'$", ""));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: almost worked!

I missed show another case and I think that is the most extreme:

`INSERT INTO tabela_1 VALUES (2,'Some data (\', hello\',)',NULL,'2016-02-10');`

In this case the output is as follows: Some date (\ 'hello \') ', NULL

In other cases it worked perfectly!

Comment: I've changed the regular expression:
`str.split("(,')|(, ')|(,\\)')|(', \\)')");`

output:

2
Some data (\', hello\
,NULL
2016-02-10

I not familiar with regular expression... :/

Comment: @UbirajaraRodrigues please see my updated answer dealing also with the NULL case.

Comment: Thanks!
But this output with a small mistake, I think because the regular expression at the entrance said the output is getting so:
'[2, Some date (\' hello \ ') more data', NULL, 02.10.2016 ']'
Without the quotation mark at the beginning of each text column.
The correct would be `'Some data'` In my output show this `Some data'`

Comment: @UbirajaraRodrigues Done, see `splitAndPrintString2` the lines: `System.out.println(prefix.replaceAll("'$", ""));` and `System.out.println(suffix.replaceAll("'$", ""));`